# docker how to connect to external DNS

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I have docker container (lets say A) running on a host (lets say X). I would like the container to be able to have outbound connectivity to a DNS (ie ELB) that host X already has access to.

ie 
container A ---> want to be able to curl an external ELB DNS endpoint...problem is container unable to resolve it!

host X ---> is able to curl the external ELB DNS endpoint already

Comment: hello?  did u try my suggestions?

Comment: this only mentions ip, does it mean all ports on that ip are mapped? what if same port is on the ip and in the docker container?

Comment: I added another reference for you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these work for you?

```
$ docker run --dns 10.0.0.2 busybox nslookup google.com
```

Or edit your /etc/docker/daemon.json similar to:

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

and restart the docker service
    $ sudo systemctl docker restart

For more information, please see [Fix Docker's networking DNS config](https://development.robinwinslow.uk/2016/06/23/fix-docker-networking-dns/) and [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).